# Trying to insert data into my local mongo database but the execution has stuck somewhere in the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node and MongoDb and has just tried to use mongoose to create a database and insert data into it in my local system.

[Here is the javascript:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsZZN.png)

I have run mongod in my root directory.
[Here is the path and execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpYhE.png)

The connection is successful and then it is stuck here.
[I am in the right path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oEs8.png)

I expected either the operation to be successful or the terminal to show any error.
But it is literally stuck here for over 5 minutes.

Earlier, I tried the execution in IPv6 in my mongodb connection url.
[Then, it showed this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IILuC.png)

After exploring a bit about this, I figured it's a version error and thus tried IPv4 instead.
[And it is just stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0OMa.png)

Can someone suggest any solution?

Comment: Kindly refrain from providing code, errors, and logs in image format. Provide them in plain text as `code format`, so people can copy the code to run and debug it.

Comment: "*After exploring a bit about this, I figured it's a version error and thus tried IPv4 instead. And it is just stuck here*"

what else do you think would happen? You haven't given any console log statements after that, neither are you closing the mongodb connection. Also check your ***fruits*** collection in ***fruitDB*** database. The data for *papaya* must have been inserted. Provide a screenshot of the data in the database collection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the mongo operations once it is successfully connected.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      rating: { type: Number, required: true },
      review: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    });
    const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
    const fruit = new Fruit({
      name: "Papaya",
      rating: 8,
      review: "Fresh and Sweet",
    });
    fruit.save();
  });
```